# Unable to Run Batch Test Classes. Please help me

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, code-coverage

I have written Batch Class which is working fine (batch class is written below), now I want to write its test class. The one I have written is not giving 100% code coverage (only 30% is covering), it's not covering from If condition. Please help me to to correct my Test Class (Test class is also written below)

**Batch Class**

```java
global class Batch_Update_Vendor_Onboarding_Stage implements Database.Batchable<sobject> {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        //String query ='Select ID,RP_Current_Stage__c FROM Vendor__c WHERE'
        String query ='Select ID,Stage_9_Partner_portal_demo__c,Name,Unique_Vendor__c,RP_Current_Stage__c,Stage_0_Draft_Vendor__c,Stage_1_Vendor_Self_Registration_link__c,Stage_2_Self_Registration_form_received__c,Stage_3_Activities_generated_for_Vendor__c,Stage_4_Validate_Details_Documents__c,Stage_5_Setup_Introductory_meeting__c,Stage_6_Request_Receive_final_signed__c,Stage_7_Update_Sourcing_Exchange_CRM__c,Stage_8_Share_Partner_Portal_Credential__c, DT_Vendor_Self_Registration_form_sent__c,Last_Submission_Date_Time__c FROM Vendor__c WHERE Stage_0_Draft_Vendor__c!=NULL';
        System.debug(Database.getQueryLocator(query));
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query); 
    }
    
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<Vendor__c> Vendorlist){
        System.debug(Vendorlist);
        for(Vendor__c V : Vendorlist){
            
            if(V.Stage_0_Draft_Vendor__c==0){
                V.RP_Current_Stage__c='Draft Vendor – No Communication';
            }else if(V.Stage_1_Vendor_Self_Registration_link__c==0){
                V.RP_Current_Stage__c='Vendor Self – Registration link';
            } else if(V.Stage_2_Self_Registration_form_received__c==0){
                V.RP_Current_Stage__c='Self–Registration form received';
            }else if(V.Stage_3_Activities_generated_for_Vendor__c==0){
                V.RP_Current_Stage__c='Activities generated for Vendor';
            }else if(V.Stage_4_Validate_Details_Documents__c==0){
                V.RP_Current_Stage__c='Validate Details & Documents';
            }else if(V.Stage_5_Setup_Introductory_meeting__c==0){
                V.RP_Current_Stage__c='Setup Introductory meeting';
            }else if(V.Stage_6_Request_Receive_final_signed__c==0){
                V.RP_Current_Stage__c='Request / Receive final signed';
            }else if(V.Stage_7_Update_Sourcing_Exchange_CRM__c==0){
                V.RP_Current_Stage__c='Update Sourcing Exchange, CRM';
            }else if(V.Stage_8_Share_Partner_Portal_Credential__c==0){
                V.RP_Current_Stage__c='Share Partner Portal Credential';
            } else if(V.Stage_9_Partner_portal_demo__c==1){
                V.RP_Current_Stage__c='Partner portal demo';
            }else{
                V.RP_Current_Stage__c='';
            }
                        
        }
        update Vendorlist;
        
    }
    
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        
    }
    
}
```

**Test Class**

```java
@isTest
public class Batch_Update_Vendor_Onboarding_StageTest {
    @isTest
    static void Batch_Update_Vendor_Onboarding_StageTest1(){
        Vendor__c ven = new Vendor__c();
        ven.Custom_Supplier_ID__c = '12345';
        ven.Unique_Vendor__c = '12345';
        //ven.Stage_0_Draft_Vendor__c = null;
        insert ven;
        Test.Starttest();
            Batch_Update_Vendor_Onboarding_Stage obj = new Batch_Update_Vendor_Onboarding_Stage();
            database.executeBatch(obj);
        Test.Stoptest();    
        Vendor__c ven1 = new Vendor__c();
        ven1 = [Select id,Stage_0_Draft_Vendor__c,Last_Submission_Date__c From Vendor__c Where id =: ven.id];
        System.debug('ven1 ' + ven);
        System.debug('ven1.Stage_0_Draft_Vendor__c '+ven1.Stage_0_Draft_Vendor__c);
    }
}
```

Please someone help me or make some changes in my Test Class.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When you're getting an error, you should _always include the full text of the error_ (and the stack trace). [Edit] your question to include that.

Comment: Please avoid using gendered language ("sir") in referring to the community. Not all of us are men and we want to be welcoming and inclusive.